# temporarily patch a command (xpatchcmd)

Tags: moderncv, xpatch

for context: I'm writing a cv with moderncv. I like the looks of it, but the package doesn't appear to allow easy layout cusomitzations.

What I want to achieve is one `\section` that formats a certain command differently than the others.

in particular I'm using

```
\xpatchcmd\cventry{,}{\newline}{}{}
```

to replace a comma by a `\newline`.
Is it possible to 'scope' the patch, such that it is only applied within, say one section?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest a different patch:

```
\xpatchcmd{\cventry}{,}{\cventrycomma}{}{}
\newcommand{\cventrycomma}{,}
```

Then you can do

```
\renewcommand{\cventrycomma}{\newline}
```

when you want to have a new line instead of a comma. The restoration can be obtained in two ways:

1. Enclose the part where you want the new line, including the `\renewcommand`, in a `\begingroup...\endgroup` pair
2. Issue `\renewcommand{\cventrycomma}{,}` when you want a comma again.

Method one can be hidden in an environment:

```
\newenvironment{specialsection}
  {\renewcommand{\cventrycomma}{\newline}}
  {}
```

Comment: this looks like what i wanted - and it will use all latexs scopes that already exist automatically :)

Comment: how would I use a parameter from the patched command (\cventry) inside the wrapped LaTeX command (\cventrycomma)?

Comment: @IARI Sorry, I don't understand

Comment: I'm sorry, I wasn't clear enough.
cventry has 5 arguments. I want to be able to use these in xpatch, or even in the new proxy-newcommand - for instance i might want to replace #1 by \emph{#1} or something like that.
If this isn't clear enouth I will write a separate question.

Comment: @IARI That's definitely a new question

Comment: I opened http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/263082/change-or-patch-a-command-using-parameters?noredirect=1#comment631103_263082

Answer (score 2):

I would do this as follows:

```
\let\originalcventry\cventry%        save a copy of \cventry
\xpatchcmd\cventry{,}{\newline}{}{}% create the patched version

...use the patched version...

\let\cventry\originalcventry%       restore the original
```

Comment: I'd suggest `\LetLtxMacro` instead of `\let`. In the sense that you restoration will *not* work.

Comment: @egreg Where is `\LetLtxMacro` defined? I don't know it (and it sounds like I should).

Comment: While that would work I don't think its a very good solution.
Assume I want to do that multiple times, with difference commands. What I really want, is an actual 'scoping' (i.e. automatically use latex environments) and not have to come up with a new variable name - it looks like boilerplate to me.

Comment: @Andrew In the `letltxmacro` package; its documentation explains why it should be used. If you test your restoration, you'll realize it doesn't work, because `\xpatchcmd` does *nothing* to the macro `\cventry`, but it acts on the internal macro `\\cventry`.