# change or patch a command using parameters

Tags: xpatch, arguments

Assume I want to use a command `\foo` from some package takes a number of arguments, let's say `#1` to `#5`.
I want to change the behavior of `\foo`
in ways that might involve these arguments.

For example assume `\foo` formats the 5 arguments in a certain fashion.
I might want to:

1. remove the first occurrence of a comma produced by `\foo`
2. output argument #5 in front of everything
3. swap arguments `#1` and `#2`
4. enclose the usage of argument `#3` with `\emph{}`

So far I've been able to accomplish 1. with xpatch like this:

```
\xpatchcmd\cventry{,}{}{}{}
```

but clearly, i cannot literally use arguments here like this

```
\xpatchcmd\cventry{#3}{\emph{#3}}{}{}
```

How can I achieve points 2. to 4. in a nice, readable generic reusable fashion?

**Note** that solutions for the other points should allow something like the following approach:

```
\xpatchcmd\cventry{,}{\cventrycomma}{}{}
\newcommand{\cventrycomma}{, }
```

where `\cventrycomma` is used to allow scope control, so in a certain \begingroup\endgroup environment `\cventrycomma` can be redefined to behave differently (if this isn't clear see also [temporarily patch a command (xpatchcmd)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/262911/temporarily-patch-a-command-xpatchcmd/262920?noredirect=1#comment631078_262920)).

Comment: It's possible (probably) but there comes a point where it's just so much easier to simply copy the original definition and edit it to your requirements. I suspect that this is well past that point.

Comment: In my opinion, solutions must be very specific to the command. I think it may happen it amounts to entirely rewriting the command. If you say what is this command, it would be easier o have a useful answer.

Comment: This might be a practical solution that just works, but I strongly believe that copy-pasting is always the wrongest thing to do and I would like to avoid it whenever it is possible.

Comment: The link to the other question is more specific. However, I'm looking for a generic solution. I believe my problem is stated in a way that it can be applied to any command, and i want a solution that can be applied to any command, if thats possible.

Comment: Remember you are working in a macro expansion language not a compiled language, there is no hiding of implementation in anycase the patch command is simply copying the implementation and has complete dependency on the tokens in that implementation inorder to make source-level changes, copying the code is often simpler and safer in that you are more resilient to changes if the original is updated.

Comment: that would be good if i wanted to be completely resilient to changes from the original - however, in my case I want developement to happen, I want standarts deveoping and comply to them and I want my command to update with a change - and a patch would do this, unless specifications of the commands used alter drastically, in which case i want the document to break and force me to reconsider the usage.